# Realistic Camera in Android

Tags: android, colors, camera, detection, sensors

I'm doing a color detector with the Android Camara and need a good parameters configuration that show me a realistic color. For example, I focus in a black shirt, but the camara take the light and change the color to light gray and i don't want it.
If someone knows how to make a good configuration I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the camera. But I would think even if you manage to find some parameters that allow what you are after, you may have to make different configuration settings because of the different hardware cameras that are present across all of the different devices.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have done it myself but I think you would need to have an Activity whose sole purpose would be to do calibration. You would be getting a live Camera feed and prompt the user to press + or - if the shirt is the black they want. The +/- would be augmenting a Color matrix filter applied to the camera view. It might be simpler to take a picture and work with the captured bitmap than it would be for the live camera feed.